# Triangulating GPS coordinates

Tags: math, gps, geometry

Say you have `n` GPS coordinates how could you work out the central GPS point between them?

Comment: Defined "central point"?  Do you want any point within a convex hull around the points, the geometric center, or what?

Comment: I am just trying to estimate my position based upon known gps coordinates of wifi access points and the signals i can get from them.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to do a least squares fit, just like the GPS does itself.  But it's complicated.

Comment: Over the distance you get wifi, you can just assume a flat plane through each gps point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case it helps anyone now or in the future, here's an algorithm that's valid even for points near the poles (if it's valid at all, i.e. if I haven't made a silly math mistake ;-):

1. Convert the latitude/longitude coordinates to 3D Cartesian coordinates:

   ```
   x = cos(lat) * cos(lon)
   y = cos(lat) * sin(lon)
   z = sin(lat)
   ```
2. Compute the average of x, the average of y, and the average of z:

   ```
   x_avg = sum(x) / count(x)
   y_avg = sum(y) / count(y)
   z_avg = sum(z) / count(z)
   ```
3. Convert that direction back to latitude and longitude:

   ```
   lat_avg = arctan(z_avg / sqrt(x_avg ** 2 + y_avg ** 2))
   lon_avg = arctan(y_avg / x_avg)
   ```

Comment: But I guess you do raise a point, an actual implementation would probably use an arctan2(num, denom) function.

Comment: I just tried implementing this and longitude is fine but latitude is way out.  Keep going back over my code and it seems ok, am I tired or is there a mistake in the algorithm?

Comment: I just rechecked it (implemented in Mathematica) and it seems to work fine for me... make sure that pi/2 radians (or +90 degrees) latitude is the north pole, 0 is the equation, and -pi/2 (or -90) is the south pole.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Here's the code I implemented http://pastebin.com/m4ff87c5a 

The longitude is coming out fine but not the latitude?

Comment: Also I didn't understand your second comment so I ignored it.  I guess that was maybe a bad move?

Comment: About the arctan2 function? That only makes a difference when x_avg is 0, so I doubt that's your problem. Or if you're talking about the degrees/radians thing: you'll have to multiply by 180/Math.PI if you're working with degrees. If that doesn't help, maybe you should start a new question about it.

Comment: P.S. If you do start a new question, I'd suggest expanding that pastebin snippet into a full Java class that at least compiles.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you mean by the central GPS point.  You could simply take the average of all the points, as suggested by Stephen - but keep in mind that GPS coordinates are not continuous - this will fail spectacularly around discontinuities such as the poles.

In most cases you'll need to convert to a coordinate system that doesn't have this issue.

You could also look at all the points bounded by it, calculated all the distances to each GPS point, and minimize the sum of the distances to all the GPS points.  You'll need to look into great circle calculations for this.

Further, each GPS might have a higher or lower degree of uncertainty, you should take that into account and weight them accordingly.

What exactly are you trying to find out?

-Adam